# ExtJS. Adding to a container an existing object removes it from a source container

Tags: javascript, extjs, copy, field, containers

I've got two containers. One is the destination and one is the source. When I use the `add` function and copy a field from the source container to the destination this field is removed from the source container. I don't find any mentions about this in the documentation. And the only solution that I see is the overriding the `add` method (but it's not good).

Is there any other solutions or maybe any options which are not mentioned in the documentation which will help to resolve this problem? Also is it a bug and should I post it to the Sencha bugtracker?

JsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/coshmos/uBKG2/1/
Case:

1. Go to the `Source` tab
2. Check the checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try modifying your last add as follows:

```
  destinationContainer.add(checkedField.cloneConfig());
```